# Python - Read second column from file

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io, readfile

My input file has two columns. I am trying to print the second column of `inputdata1.txt` within a second for-loop. But my code is not working. Can someone tell me what should I do?

Comment: You should show the code that "_is not working_" and explain what "_is not working_" means in more details.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to explain how the columns are separated in inputdata1.txt

Comment: If you are dealing with a csv file (despite of the file extension being .txt), you can try using a `csv` library

Answer (score 13):

```
with open('inputdata1.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        parts = line.split() # split line into parts
        if len(parts) > 1:   # if at least 2 parts/columns
            print parts[1]   # print column 2
```

This assumes the columns are separated by whitespace.

Function [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) can specify different separators. For instance if the columns were separated with commas `,` you'd use `line.split(',')` in the code above.

NOTE: Using `with` to open your file *automatically closes it* when you are done, or if you encounter an *exception*.

Comment: `line.strip()` is redundant if it is followed by `line.split()`

Comment: it doesnt print all the values in the column, it prints only the first value

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this. `Separator` is the character your file uses to separate colums, e.g. tabs or commas.

```
for line in open("inputfile.txt"):
    columns = line.split(separator)
    if len(columns) >= 2:
        print columns[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Quick 'n dirty**

If AWK is installed:

```
# $2 for the second column
os.system("awk '{print $2}' inputdata1.txt")
```

---

**Using a class**

Make a class:

```
class getCol:
    matrix = []
    def __init__(self, file, delim=" "):
        with open(file, 'rU') as f:
            getCol.matrix =  [filter(None, l.split(delim)) for l in f]

    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        column = []
        for row in getCol.matrix:
            try:
                column.append(row[key])
            except IndexError:
                # pass
                column.append("")
        return column
```

If `inputdata1.txt` would look like:

```
hel   lo   wor   ld
wor   ld   hel   lo
```

You would get this:

```py
print getCol('inputdata1.txt')[1]
#['lo', 'ld']
```

---

**Additional notes**

- You can use [`pyawk`](http://pyawk.sourceforge.net/) for more awk features
- If you're using the Quick 'n dirty method use `subprocess.Popen`
- You can change the delimiter `getCol('inputdata1.txt', delim=", ")`
- Use `filter` to remove empty values or uncomment `pass`

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file_to_read.txt") # open your file

line = f.readline().strip() # get the first line in line

while line: # while a line exists in the file f
    columns = line.split('separator') # get all the columns
    while columns: # while a column exists in the line
        print columns # print the column
    line = f.readline().strip() # get the next line if it exists
```

With this code, you have access to all columns of each line.